'react/debug/react_native_assert.h' file not found xcode issue occured when i configured firebase in my project
'react/debug/react_native_assert.h' file not found xcode
how to solved this issue ?
issue occurred when i integrated firebase ios app in my project and did pod install --repo-update pod is installed but in xCode build is failed and it failing again and again tried all possible solutions but not worked for me

Did you find a solution?
